# Solving Nonlinear Differential Equation Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[My Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFz40.jpg)

First I let u = y' and employed the Chain Rule to obtain du/dx = du/dy * u

But I am not sure where to go from there. Any tips, suggestions, or solutions to the problem would be much appreciated!

I suspect there may also be different families of solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Divide both sides by $y^2$:
$$ y'' = \frac{y'}{y^2}. $$
Now, both sides are total derivatives:
$$ (y')' = \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)', $$
so integrating both sides,
$$ y' = \frac{Ay-1}{y}, $$
and dividing through,
$$ \frac{y}{Ay-1} y' =1, $$
which is easy to integrate by using partial fractions.

Comment: Is the second step mathematically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Chappers's final result $$\frac{y}{Ay-1} \frac{dy}{dx} =1$$ which is separable. Write it as $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y}{Ay-1}= \frac 1A\frac{Ay-1+1}{Ay-1}= \frac 1A\left(1+\frac{1}{Ay-1}\right)$$ and integrate both sides; so $$x+B=\frac{\log (1-A y)}{A^2}+\frac{y}{A}$$ and solving for $y$ $$y=\frac{W\left(-e^{A^2 (x+B)-1}\right)+1}{A}$$ where appears Lambert function.

Remember that any equation which can write $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has solutions in terms of Lambert function.